# NASM TO GAS: counterpart of resw in GAS

Tags: assembly, nasm, gnu-assembler

I am tasked to convert my assembly program which uses NASM to GAS. Unfortunately there are lots of mismatched statements. I have converted some of them but I am still having trouble on how to convert this statement

```
min resw 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Reserving *one* word (with an initializer of 0) is pretty easy:

```
min:    .word    0
```

For x86, `.word` is 16-bit.  For other sizes: `.byte`, `.long`, `.quad`.

---

If you wanted to reserve a large chunk, say 50 words, use the `.fill` or `.space` directives:

```
buff1:  .fill    50, 1, 0     # count, size, value
buff2:  .space   50, 0        # count (bytes), value (defaults to 0)
```

For initializers with a repeating pattern wider than 1 byte, [`.dcb.size`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Dcb.html) takes a value and length:

```
int_array:  .dcb.l  50, 12345       # 32-bit integer 12345 repeated 50 times
```

Comment: gas has a `.space size,fill` directive which _"emits `size` bytes, each of value `fill`. Both `size` and `fill` are absolute expressions. If the comma and `fill` are omitted, `fill` is assumed to be zero."_

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
.lcomm min, 2
```

or

```
.comm min, 2
```

to put aside space for two bytes (one word) in the bss section.  The point of the bss section is that the loader will allocate space and set the content to zero on load, but it won't take up space in your file on disk.

`.lcomm` is if you only need to refer to `min` from inside the file where you use `.lcomm`.  `comm` is if you need to refer to `min` from other files (so the linker will make it available to other files).

If you prefer to use the data section, which will put the zeros in your file and take up space on disk, then this, placed in the data section, should work:

```
min:
    .fill 2
```